# Create temp table with case expression

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, temp-tables

I'm trying to create a temp table with case expressions

```
insert INTO #Players_score (id , score)
SELECT( 
CASE WHEN [score] = 1 THEN 'good'
WHEN [score] = 2 THEN 'very good'
ELSE' excelent'  END) as score
FROM players
```

any suggestions on how to write it right?

Comment: You specify 2 insert columns, but only select 1 column. Should be same number.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this? It assumes that `score` exists in the table `players`.

```
INSERT INTO #Players_score (id,score)
SELECT 
   id
    ,CASE 
        WHEN [score] = 1
            THEN 'good'
        WHEN [score] = 2
            THEN 'very good'
        ELSE 'excellent'
        END AS score
FROM players
```

Comment: You're welcome. If you wouldn't mind, please consider clicking on the grey check mark to the left to mark this as your accepted answer. We will each get some reputation points, and other users will know the question has an answer. Thanks.